# parameter to builtin must be a string constant or literal

Tags: c, gcc, built-in

I am trying to use __builtin_cpu_supports not with a literal, but with a string but it fails.

Code:

```
const char s[] = "cmov";
__builtin_cpu_supports(s);
const char *t = "cmov";
__builtin_cpu_supports(t);
```

Result:

```
builtin_support.c:25:5: error: parameter to builtin must be a string constant or literal
   25 |     __builtin_cpu_supports(s);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
builtin_support.c:27:5: error: parameter to builtin must be a string constant or literal
   27 |     __builtin_cpu_supports(t);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Why?

Comment: Looking for `__builtin_cpu_supports("cmov")`?

Comment: Have you tried `__builtin_cpu_supports(“cmov”);`?

Comment: As mentioned I don't want to use a literal.

Comment: Perhaps you can write your own function which has one literal case for each possible value? `if (!strcmp(arg, "cmov")) return __builtin_cpu_supports("cmov"); else if ... `

Comment: Why? I can't find the source for `__builtin_cpu_supports` but it is likely that it uses macros or other **compile time** conditions to generate the appropriate code to test if the given instruction is supported. That can't work on anything but literals.

Comment: I just wanted to operate on a list. Looks like that will not be possible

Answer (score 0):

Ok for some reason and contrary to the error message the built-in function only wants a literal, not a string.

Using directly CPUID looks more convenient.

```
#include <cpuid.h>
unsigned int eax, ebx, ecx, edx;
__get_cpuid(0x01, &eax, &ebx, &ecx, &edx);
```